# PHP - Not able to get content with fread

Tags: php, caching, fread

I am trying to get the API data from a cache file if there already was the same request recently. Everything works fine but I am just not able to get the content from the cache file even tho it is there. I can't find an error. I hope u can help me.

```
$url = /* API URL */;

function getJson($url) {
$cacheFile = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url) . '.json';

if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'r');
    $cacheTime = filemtime($cacheFile);

    if ($cacheTime > strtotime('-60 minutes')) {
        $json = fread($fh);
        return $json;
    }

    fclose($fh);
    unlink($cacheFile);
}

$json = file_get_contents($url); 


$fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);

return $json;
}

$datab = getJson($url);

$data = json_decode($datab, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: so try flushing the cache; you may have something already there. check for errors too, could be a permissions thing also. do a var_dump

Comment: Length in [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) does not seem to be optional.

Comment: @apokryfos you are right, changed it to fread($fh, filesize($cacheFile)); and set a default timezone. Now it works. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Il you dont check for your error log or display errors on screen you gonna have a bad time finding its.

Here you have a $cacheFile which should be a $cachePath, so prefix with './' or better **DIR**

Then you call fread without second parameter, and so on...check your error log, enable all errors.

Comment: *"which should be a $cachePath"* - Huh? There is no such variable defined in their code.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the length that needs to be read in `fread`.

Use:

```
if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'r');
    $cacheTime = filemtime($cacheFile);

    if ($cacheTime > strtotime('-60 minutes')) {
        $json = fread($fh,filesize($cacheFile));
        fclose($fh); //Remember to release resources
        return $json;
    }

    fclose($fh);
    unlink($cacheFile);
}
```

Alternatively use `file_get_contents($cacheFile)` to get the whole file without the need for an `fopen` first.